# Cleanup custom event from ref in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, eslint

I have a custom element, that dispatch a custom event in react.
Since there is no way to bind the event simply, I need to create a `eventListener` manually and remove it.

I tried :

```
export function App() {
  const textRef = useRef<DemoTextElement>(null);
  let eventRef;
  const logEvent = (e) => {
    console.log(e)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if(textRef.current) {
      eventRef = textRef.current;
      textRef.current.addEventListener('onCustomEvent', logEvent)
    }
    return () => {
      if(eventRef) {
          eventRef.removeEventListener('onCustomEvent', logEvent)
      }
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className={styles.app}>
      <demo-text ref={textRef}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

but I get prompted that

> Assignments to the 'eventRef' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly inside useEffect.

but I am, already using useRef hook, so I don't exactly know how to fix this... Cause I can't add useRef hook inside useEffect hook.

Comment: Could you please clarify where you declare the `counter` ref? edit example please

Comment: @RamanNikitsenka sorry that a typo while I copied

Comment: You may refer to useCallBack hook.

Comment: How would this change ? it trigger the same problems.

Comment: seems, that you don't need to use additional variable eventRef. Use instead `textRef.current.removeEventListener` inside cleanup function

Answer (score 3):

The `eventRef` variable will be re-declared for each rendering. Just move it inside `useEffect` hooks and do the assignment operation.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export default function Test() {
  const textRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const logEvent = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const eventRef = textRef.current;
    if (eventRef) {
      eventRef.addEventListener('onCustomEvent', logEvent);
    }
    return () => {
      if (eventRef) {
        eventRef.removeEventListener('onCustomEvent', logEvent);
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return <div ref={textRef}>123</div>;
}
```

Comment: yeah, I actually missread the thing, is this ok practice ? and does it work ? if so thanks